# C++ implementation of template class with pure virtual functions in it

Tags: c++, templates, pure-virtual

I'm working on a calculator that has to be able to work on different types of data (even not math data, eventually) but I'm stuck in the implementation of the `Complex` number class. Here is what I want to achieve:

- An abstract template class called `vectorSpace` from which I will derive other concrete classes like `Complex` numbers, **Vector**s, and so on.

Why do I want to create it like this? Well, the only common characteristic of **ALL** the vector spaces is that they allow two operations: **sum** operation with the same type of space, and **dot product** (or **scalar product**? Not sure of the actual name in English) in the same field. The field could be of very different types (**integer**, **double**, **strings**, etc) so I want to make it with a **template**. Every derivative class will then specify the data type of the field to the template and implement the virtual operations

- A derivative class `Complex` that will derive from `vectorSpace`, specifying double as data type, defining the operations of **sum** and **dot product**, and then adding all the rest of the available operations.

This is my code in this moment for `vectorSpace` class (entirely written in a .h file):

```
#ifndef VECTORSPACE_H
#define VECTORSPACE_H

template <class T>
class vectorSpace
{
public:
    virtual vectorSpace<T>& sum(const vectorSpace<T>&) const =0;
    virtual vectorSpace<T>& dotProduct(const T&) const =0;
};

#endif // VECTORSPACE_H
```

In complex.h I have this:

```
#ifndef COMPLEX_H
#define COMPLEX_H

#include "vectorspace.h"

class Complex : public vectorSpace<double> {
private:
    double re, im;
public:
    Complex(double r=0, double i=0);

    double real() const;
    double imag() const;

    Complex& operator +(const Complex& z) const;
    Complex& sum(const Complex& z) const;
    Complex& operator *(double d) const;
    Complex dotProduct(double d) const;
    //other functions for Complex

};

#endif // COMPLEX_H
```

and finally the implementation I've done:

```
#include "complex.h"

Complex::Complex(double r, double i) : re(r), im(i) {}

double Complex::real() const{
    return re;
}

double Complex::imag() const{
    return im;
}

Complex& Complex::operator +(const Complex& z) const{
    Complex *aux = new Complex(); //new is not allowed for an abstract class but it should not be abstract anymore
    aux->re = re + z->re;
    aux->im = im + z->im;
    return *aux;
}

Complex& Complex::sum(const Complex &z) const{
    return *this + z;
}

/* I've tried even with this, but it does not work!!
vectorSpace<double>& Complex:sum(const vectorSpace<double>& z) const{
    return *this + z;
}
*/

Complex Complex::operator *(double d) const{
    Complex aux;
    aux.re = re * d;
    aux.im = im * d;
    return aux;
}

Complex& Complex::dotProduct(const double& d) const{
    return *this * d;
}
```

This is just the last implementation attempt I've done. I've tried various combinations, but still I can't get my `Complex` class to get it recognized as concrete instead of abstract. Where do I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**The problem**:

You need to override the following pure virtual member methods of the abstract template class `vectorSpace` in your concrete derived class `Complex`:

```
virtual vectorSpace<T>& sum(const vectorSpace<T>&) const = 0;
virtual vectorSpace<T>& dotProduct(const T&) const = 0;
```

Currently, you provide two overloaded member methods, but these are no overrides (try compiling after adding the `override` keyword to both of these member methods) due to the use of different return types (i.e. `Complex&` != `vectorSpace<double>&`):

```
Complex& Complex::sum(const Complex &z) const {
    return *this + z;
}

Complex& Complex::dotProduct(const double& d) const {
    return *this * d;
}
```

**A possible solution**:

Pass `Complex` as an additional template parameter to the base class `vectorSpace`. Change the signature of the pure virtual member methods using this additional template parameter's type.

**A possible implementation** [[Try It Online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/q3FeCQE0AgLMRqrZ)]:

```
template< typename T, typename ValueT >
class VectorSpace {

public:

    virtual const ValueT sum(const ValueT&) const noexcept = 0;
    virtual const ValueT dotProduct(T) const noexcept = 0;
};

class Complex : public VectorSpace< double, Complex > {

private:

    double re, im;

public:

    Complex(double r, double i) noexcept 
        : re(r), im(i) {}

    // Do not worry about the const return values; 
    // C++17's Guaranteed Copy Elision will take care of that.

    const Complex operator+(const Complex& z) const noexcept {
        return Complex(re + z.re, im + z.im);
    }

    const Complex operator*(double d) const noexcept {
        return Complex(re * d, im * d);
    }

    const Complex sum(const Complex& z) const noexcept override {
        return *this + z;
    }
    const Complex dotProduct(double d) const noexcept override {
        // Note that this is not a general dot or inner product.
        // This is just scalar multiplication.
        return *this * d;
    }
};

int main() {
    Complex c(1.0, 2.0); // As concrete as can be ;-)
    return 0;
}
```

I made a few changes, since your heap allocations are pure overhead and dangerous, and you cannot pass a non-`const` reference to an instance using a `const` member method of that instance unless you really want to misuse a `const_cast`).

Comment: Tip: using the `override` keyword can be quite helpful in determining whether a function that's supposed to override actually does.

Comment: If you use static polymorphism like this you can avoid virtual functions altogether: `VectorSpace` knows the derived type `ValueT`, so it can directly call its functions.

Comment: @JesperJuhl thanks for the advice... I tried override AFTER writing my post. I thought that as Complex was declared as subclass of vectorSpace, it would have accepted an ovverride using a subclass type as return values and parameters, as they were a vectorSpace too...
But the point now is: will the function work if it expects a vectorSpace as a parameter and I pass a Complex that's a subclass of it? And what will have I to do with the returned value? Will it have to be a vectorSpace when I use return? I suppose it should work even with a Complex object too

Comment: @Matthias thanks for the advice. I've understood the problem of the wrong implementation as Complex& sum(...)... etc. But I have to admit that I don't know different parts of your code: the use of noexcept keyword; the use of two types of parameters for the template; the difference between class T and typename T. So I would have never been able to write a code like yours :-(
And still I can't understand why should the functions of complex return const return values.

Comment: (i) For `noexcept`, just Google it. Though it can be deduced in this example, so it is not strictly necessary. (ii) A second template parameter is added to let the base class know about the type of a derived class. (iii) If you really prefer `class` over `typename`, just use (and "overload") `class` instead. (iv) Why do you want to return by non-`const` value (assuming C++17; for < C++17 you may remove the `const`)?